# Adding Input Operator Dynamically to a running Apache Apex application

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-apex, bigdata

Is it possible to add input operator for different source in the running Apex application?
For example: In an production environment, I am running an Apex application to read the text-file from input source and I want to add Kafka source with its input operator to the same DAG.

Answer (score 3):

Priyanshu,
You can have multiple input operators. Just add kafka input operator to you dag.

http://docs.datatorrent.com/library_operators/

Amol